# Is it possible to check if any of the field in a mysql row is empty?

Tags: mysql

Ran into a brick wall & I came running here for help.

Is it possible to check if a field is empty in a given mysql table row and no, I do not want to check by each column name ( with a single line sql if possible).

I would elaborate some more:

say if I have a table with columns t1_col1,t1_col2 and ...

so I would like to know if any of these columns is empty.

and if I have another table with columns t2_col1, t2_col2 and ..

I would like to use the SAME sql statement to check if any of these columns are empty.

I have not tried anything, because I do not know what to try, I know it is possible to achieve this by checking if column are null ( if column names are known that is and also I know column names of table can be found by 'show column' of mysql). So those are not the way I want to go. I want to know if there is any single command that can do this checking ?

Can any body help me please.

Comment: What do you mean "I do not want to check by each column name"? You want to know if any column in the row is empty?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no such thing in MySQL. You will have to check each column.

However, it is possible to get the table schema like this:

```
DESCRIBE table_name;
```

It will give you a list of all columns in the table, then using your favorite programming language, you can cycle over all fields to create a query to check if they are empty.